# How to add "unlike" button in web page?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-app-requests

I am working on Windows 8 App where I need to show a web page with facebook "Like/Unlike" options. Below is code which I added for Like.I need to add Unlike option too. Can some one explain me how to get this done ?

```
    @section AdditionalHeaderContent {

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    }
@section ContentFooter
 {
    <div id="fb-root">
    <fb:like ref="@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().EnsureTrailing("/")" show_faces="true" width="450"></fb:like>        
    </div>
}
```

How can I show "unlike" button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook like button also is your Facebook unlike button. The Facebook button knows if you already liked the page.

So when you click on it again you are "unlike-ing" it again.

**update ** *(so you do not have to check the comments)*

This button uses Javascript that has been hosted by facebook, you can not edit that.

**----- What you can do ----**

If it is possible to make a custom separate Like and "Unlike" button this would be the way to do it.

Use the c# Facebook SDK to code things for Facebook yourself.
( http://csharpsdk.org/ )

You can look up the Facebook API here. 
( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/ )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to display both Like and Unlike buttons. Assume, There is a web page where we are displaying list of suggestions and User has Like/Dislike on each suggestion. (In this scenario I cant display unlike option after user clicks on 
"Like")

Comment: Also, CUrrently, my application is not showing "Unlike" option after clicking like. Can you tell me code snippet for this?

Comment: I do not think there is such a button. At least not from facebook itself.

The facebook button changes into an Unlike button once uve liked the page. (the button becomes gray)

But since u are using this in a win 8 app (just noticed it). Did you test if "clicking like" actually works? Isn't it better to use the Facebook SDK instead?

Comment: A small update. Check this page  http://rankingthebrands.com/Brand-detail.aspx?brandID=8 . When u click on the like (like-ing) button u see it becomes Gray. But when u click it again (unlike-ing) it switches to normal again.

Comment: Hello Vansanten, Thanks for your reply. That is exactly happening in my application.My Application has to show both likes and dislikes. We cant consider not clicking on "Like" is dislike. At least can you point me some spinet where I can change to "Unlike" after clicking like?

Comment: You can not do that with this button. You can probably do this when you write the code yourself using the Facebook SDK. ( http://csharpsdk.org/ ) 

This is the FB like button documentation. That is all you can do with that button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: FB API Doc.  : ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/ )

The button you are using now is using a javascript that is hosted by facebook. You can not change that.

Comment: Thanks vanSanten, Seems I need to explore further.

Comment: Thanks again, Do you have any example where you can point me for my requirement? I am planning to implement MVC webpage and will call that URL from my Windows 8 App. Any webpage implementation will also helps.(at least I should display Unlike after clicking like)..Really appreciate your help though...